# Spock mocks showing up as nulls

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

Here is my main class:

```
@Slf4j
class ConsoleReaderWorker implements Runnable {
    ConsoleReader reader
    Writer writer
    RemoteCommandSelector commandSelector

    @Inject
    ConsoleReaderWorker(ConsoleReader reader, Writer writer, RemoteCommandSelector commandSelector) {
        super()
        this.reader = reader
        this.writer = writer
        this.commandSelector = commandSelector
    }

    @Override
    void run() {
        try {
            String line
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                commandSelector.select(line).execute(writer)
                writer.flush()
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            log.warn("${this} interrupted with: ${ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex)}")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my attempt at a Spock `Specification` for that class:

```
class ConsoleReaderWorkerSpec extends Specification {
    def "when enter key is pressed then a command is selected and executed and the writer is flushed"() {
        given: "a running fixture with some mock dependencies"
        ConsoleReader reader = Mock(ConsoleReader)
        Writer writer = Mock(Writer)
        RemoteCommand command = Mock(RemoteCommand)
        RemoteCommandSelector commandSelector = Mock(RemoteCommandSelector)

        reader.readLine() >> '\n'
        commandSelector.select(_) >> command

        ConsoleReaderWorker worker = new ConsoleReaderWorker(reader, writer, commandSelector)

        when: "the enter key is pressed"
        worker.run()

        then: "a command is executed"
        1 * commandSelector.select(_)
    }
}
```

Essentially, I want to confirm that when the `run()` method is invoked, that the `commandSelector#select()` method is invoked with *any* argument.

When I run this I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method execute() on null object
    at com.nocbots.nbsvc.remote.cli.jline.ConsoleReaderWorker.run(ConsoleReaderWorker.groovy:33)
    at com.nocbots.nbsvc.remote.cli.jline.ConsoleReaderWorkerSpec.when enter key is pressed then a command is selected and executed and the writer is flushed(ConsoleReaderWorkerSpec.groovy:25)
```

Line 33 of `ConsoleReadyWorker` is the call to `commandSelector.select()` that lives inside the `while` loop:

```
commandSelector.select(line).execute(writer)
```

Any ideas as to why?!? As you can see, I've wired `commandSelector#select()` mock to return the `RemoteCommand` mock, so it should never be null...ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
then: "a command is executed"
1 * commandSelector.select(_) >> command
```

instead of:

```
commandSelector.select(_) >> command
```

Please have a look at the [docs](https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html). When you both mock and verify, `then` block should be used.

**EDIT**

This is spock related error you're getting, trust me. Have a look at the runnable script below (can be run using groovy console):

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class ConsoleReaderWorkerSpec extends Specification {
    def "when enter key is pressed then a command is selected and executed and the writer is flushed"() {
        given: "a running fixture with some mock dependencies"
        ConsoleReader reader = Mock(ConsoleReader)
        Writer writer = Mock(Writer)
        RemoteCommand command = Mock(RemoteCommand)
        RemoteCommandSelector commandSelector = Mock(RemoteCommandSelector)

        reader.readLine() >> '\n'

        ConsoleReaderWorker worker = new ConsoleReaderWorker(reader, writer, commandSelector)

        when: "the enter key is pressed"
        worker.run()

        then: "a command is executed"
        1 * commandSelector.select(_) >> command
    }
}

class ConsoleReaderWorker implements Runnable {

    ConsoleReader reader
    Writer writer
    RemoteCommandSelector commandSelector

    ConsoleReaderWorker(ConsoleReader reader, Writer writer, RemoteCommandSelector commandSelector) {
        this.reader = reader
        this.writer = writer
        this.commandSelector = commandSelector
    }

    @Override
    void run() {
        try {
            String line
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                commandSelector.select(line).execute(writer)
                writer.flush()
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            log.warn("${this} interrupted with: ${ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex)}")
        }
    }
}
class Writer {
   void flush() {}
}
class RemoteCommand {
   void execute(Writer w) {

   }
}
class ConsoleReader {
   String readLine() {
      ''
   }
}
class RemoteCommandSelector {
   RemoteCommand select(o) {
      new RemoteCommand()
   }
}
```

It fails since `select` is invoked twice, but does not fail with NPE. To fix it add the following line:

```
reader.readLine() >>> ['\n', null]
```

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - but **heh?!?** Please look closer at my Spock spec. My code *is* after a `then` block (in fact, verbatim: `then: "a command is executed"`). And my mock is (again, verbatim): `1 * commandSelector.select(_)`. **Most importantly** its not even a Spock related error I'm getting. If you read my question, you'll see I'm getting a NPE in the main class because Spock isn't (for some reason) properly honoring the mock I set up. I feel like you didn't fully read my question. If you did, please provide a *full* code example to put your answer in better context. Thanks again!