# How to mock EntityManager and Query with Spock?

Tags: unit-testing, jpa, spock

Using spock I need to mock the calls to `EntityManager`/`Query`. The line of code I'm trying to mock is:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("nativeQuery").setParameter(1, param1).getResultList()
```

The mock of `entityManager.createNativeQuery` returns a null `Query` object. That then causes a failure because you can't call a method on a null object. And I consequently I can't mock the return of a result set list.

I've tried breaking the statement down into separate ones and accompanying mocks, but that hasn't worked either because I still end up with a null Query.

I don't know if I've got tunnelvision on this right now, or if this can't be mocked - at least with Spock.

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to build a hierarchy of mocks which will be returning each other, starting with the last one:

Query:

```
def query = Mock(Query) {
   setParameter(_, _) >> it //here as mock itself is returned
   getResultList() >> []    //empty list
}
```

EntityManager:

```
def manager = Mock(EntityManager) {
   createNativeQuery(_) >> query
}
```

And so on. While what you need to implement is doable it more or less indicates bad design: *every time a mock returns a mock a fairy dies*, so you should avoid such constructs. What you can do is to separate query building from it's execution - then mocking will be much easier. Sample spec:

```
def 'fairy has just died'() {
   given:
   def query = Mock(Query) {
      setParameter(_, _) >> it //here as mock itself is returned
      getResultList() >> [1]    //empty list
   }

   def manager = Mock(EntityManager) {
      createNativeQuery(_) >> query
   }

   expect:
   manager.createNativeQuery("").setParameter(1,1).getResultList() == [1]
}
```

Comment: I love the description of a mock returning a mock! Unfortunately I'm getting the error I've been getting about not being able to **setParameter** on null object.

Comment: @Les, share the whole specification, please.

Comment: Just a guess - it might be related to this answer (mocking and verification) at the same time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35059223/spock-mocks-showing-up-as-nulls/35059281#35059281

Comment: I was wrong. I had a typo. There isn't a method _create**Native**Query_ - it's _create**Named**Query_. Once I corrected that your solution worked perfectly! Thanks.